# Twilio .NET API CallStatus Enum comparison?

Tags: vb.net, twilio

I'm updating my Twilio to use the newer library (5.x)

I create a phone call using the new API. I want to check the status of the call.

```
Dim CallStatus = MyTwilioCall.Status
If CallStatus.Equals(CallResource.StatusEnum.Queued) Then '// Success
```

This does not work, it evaluates to false, although when i debug and inspect it shows that callstatus has a value of {queued}.

If i try:

```
  If CallStatus = CallResource.StatusEnum.Ringing Then '// Success
```

I get an exception that Operator of '=' is not defined for CallResource.StatusEnum. For fun, i tried using the is operator as well with no success. I supposed i could .tostring() and then compare, but that seems silly. Am i doing something wrong, or is this just the way twilio client is built?

Comment: From the exception it sounds like ` MyTwilioCall.Status` is not a `CallResource.StatusEnum` type

Comment: It's a known issue in the 5.x library. Fix coming soon. The workaround is to call ToString() on both sides of the comparison, e.g. If CallStatus.ToString() = CallResource.StatusEnum.Ringing.ToString() Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer Educator here. You did indeed find a bug that we have since fixed in v5.1.1 of the library. If you use NuGet to upgrade to v5.1.1 or later, that should solve the problem for you.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio/5.1.1

Comment: Thanks. Do i get any twilio swag for bug finding? :)

Comment: Absolutely! Email me your mailing address at my SO username at twilio dot com